# jquery mouseout event problem12

Tags: jquery

This is my code
But onmouseout()  is not called properly because inside the div i have 2 elements one is div and other is span whose display property is none
and i have to use it because i have to call function from body
so plz help me

```
<html>
<head>
        <title>example</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../jsfile/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
        <script>
            var g_id;
            function show_slide(temp){
                var sub_str=temp.id.substring(11);
                sub_str++;
                $('#'+temp.id).animate({
                    'width':360},
                    function(){
                        $('#div-slide-image'+sub_str).hide();//hide preious div
                        $('#div-'+temp.id).animate({'width':'50%'});//increase width
                        $('#s_'+temp.id).show();   //show span tag
                    }
                );
            }    

                function hide_slide(temp){
                    var sub_str=temp.id.substring(11);
                    sub_str++;
                    $('#'+temp.id).animate({
                       'width':360},
                       function(){
                           $('#div-slide-image'+sub_str).show();//show next div which is hide previous
                           $('#div-'+temp.id).width('25%');//set width to original
                           $('#s_'+temp.id).hide(); //hide span again
                       }
                   );
                }

                function show_right_slide(temp){
                    var sub_str=temp.id.substring(15);
                    $('#s_slide-image'+sub_str).show();   //show span tag
                    sub_str--;
                    $("#"+temp.id).animate({
                            'width':'50%'},
                            function(){
                                $("#div-slide-image"+sub_str).remove();
                    });

                 }


                 function get_id(temp){
                     var sub_str=temp.id.substring(15);
                     sub_str--;
                     $('#'+temp.id).width('25%');
                     $('#div-slide-image'+sub_str).show();    
                     //alert("abc");

                 }


        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container clearfix">
            <div class="header">
                <h1>Slide Image</h1>
            </div>
            <!--left Block 1-->
            <div id="div-slide-image0" style="background-color: green;">
                <img src="images/india.jpg" alt="indian flag" id="slide-image0"  onmouseover="show_slide(this)" onmouseout="hide_slide(this)" />
                <span id="s_slide-image0">India</span>
            </div>
            <!--left Block 2-->
            <div id="div-slide-image1" style="background-color: brown;" >
                <img src="images/america.jpg" alt="indian flag" id="slide-image1" onmouseover="show_slide(this)" onmouseout="hide_slide(this)"/>
                <span id="s_slide-image1">America</span>
            </div>
            <!--right Block 1-->
            <div id="div-slide-image2" style="background-color: yellow;" onmouseover="show_right_slide(this)" onmouseout="get_id(this)">
                <img src="images/england.jpg" alt="indian flag" id="slide-image2"/>
                <span id="s_slide-image2">England</span>
            </div>
            <!--right Block 2-->
            <div id="div-slide-image3" style="background-color: orange;">
                <img src="images/Europe.jpg" alt="indian flag" id="slide-image3"/>
                <span id="s_slide-image3">Europe</span>
            </div>
            <!--left Block 3-->
            <div id="div-slide-image4" style="background-color: aquamarine;" >
                <img src="images/pakistan.png" alt="indian flag" id="slide-image4"  onmouseover="show_slide(this)" onmouseout="hide_slide(this)"/>
                <span id="s_slide-image4">Pakistan</span>
            </div>
            <!--left Block 4-->
            <div id="div-slide-image5" style="background-color:  blueviolet"  >
                <img src="images/japan.jpg" alt="indian flag" id="slide-image5" onmouseover="show_slide(this)" onmouseout="hide_slide(this)"/>
                <span id="s_slide-image5">Japan</span>
            </div>
            <!--right Block 3-->
            <div id="div-slide-image6" style="background-color: gold;">
                <img src="images/australia.jpg" alt="indian flag" id="slide-image6"/>
                <span id="s_slide-image6">Australia</span>
            </div>
            <!--right Block 4-->
            <div id="div-slide-image7" style="background-color: windowframe;">
                <img src="images/china.jpg" alt="indian flag" id="slide-image7"/>
                <span id="s_slide-image7">China</span>
            </div>
        </div>            
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you provide it on jsfiddle, please? So I can play with it and maybe I can solve your problem.

Comment: can you elobrate what you are trying to achieve

Comment: instead of inline event handler, I would suggest you to use jquery for binding the events like `$('#div-slide-image0').on('mouseout',function(){});`

Answer (score 0):

**CSS**

```
span.none{display:none;position: absolute;top: 34%;left: 60%;}
div.parent{width:25%;position:relative;} 
img.animate{position:relative;}
```

**Html**

```
<div class="container clearfix">
            <div class="header">
                <h1>Slide Image</h1>
            </div>
            <!--left Block 1-->
            <div class="parent" style="background-color: green;">
                <img class="animate" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRZfUb3hdn5JdY_RKyOJUXApu4zymfH_Kp-6JZTdznH3_oHLh4DbQ" alt="indian flag"  />
                <span class="none">India</span>
            </div>
             <div  class="parent" style="background-color: brown;">
                <img class="animate" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRZfUb3hdn5JdY_RKyOJUXApu4zymfH_Kp-6JZTdznH3_oHLh4DbQ" alt="America flag"  />
                <span  class="none">America</span>
            </div>
            <div class="parent"  style="background-color: yellow;">
                <img class="animate" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRZfUb3hdn5JdY_RKyOJUXApu4zymfH_Kp-6JZTdznH3_oHLh4DbQ" alt="England flag"  />
                <span  class="none">England</span>
            </div>

            <div  class="parent"  style="background-color: orange;">
                <img class="animate" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRZfUb3hdn5JdY_RKyOJUXApu4zymfH_Kp-6JZTdznH3_oHLh4DbQ" alt="England flag"  />
                <span  class="none">Europe</span>
            </div>
            <div class="parent"  style="background-color: aquamarine;">
                <img class="animate"  src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRZfUb3hdn5JdY_RKyOJUXApu4zymfH_Kp-6JZTdznH3_oHLh4DbQ" alt="Pakistan flag"  />
                <span  class="none">Pakistan</span>
            </div>
           <div  class="parent"  style="background-color: gold;">
                <img  class="animate" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRZfUb3hdn5JdY_RKyOJUXApu4zymfH_Kp-6JZTdznH3_oHLh4DbQ" alt="Japan flag"  />
                <span  class="none">Japan</span>
            </div>
            <div class="parent"  style="background-color: red;">
                <img class="animate" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRZfUb3hdn5JdY_RKyOJUXApu4zymfH_Kp-6JZTdznH3_oHLh4DbQ" alt="Australia flag"  />
                <span  class="none">Australia</span>
            </div>
           <div  class="parent"  style="background-color: grey;">
                <img class="animate"  src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRZfUb3hdn5JdY_RKyOJUXApu4zymfH_Kp-6JZTdznH3_oHLh4DbQ" alt="China flag"  />
                <span class="none">China</span>
            </div>

        </div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
         $('.animate').mouseover(function() { 
            $(this).animate({ left: "100px" }); //sliding the flag image to 100px from left
            $(this).parent().filter(':not(:animated)').animate({ width: "50%" }); // $(this).parent() finds the parent i.e div
            $(this).next().show();  // $(this).next() finds the next subling i.e span
            })
            .mouseout(function() {
            $(this).animate({ left: "0px" });  //sliding back the flag image to 0px to left
                $(this).parent().animate({ 'width':'25%' });// $(this).parent() finds the parent i.e div
                $(this).next().hide(); // $(this).next() finds the next subling i.e span
            });
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nadeemmnn2007/duwppwuy/)

Comment: Rate my answer if it helped you :)